# Searching multiple types in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a usecase where there are two different types in the same index. Both the types have different structure and mapping.

I need to query both types at the same time using different query DSL.

How can I build my query DSL to simultaneously query more than one type of the same index.

I looked into elasticsearch guide at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html but there is no proper explanation here. According to this even if I set two different types in my request :

```
/index/type1,type2/_search
```

I will have to send the same query DSL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [multi-search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) and the `_msearch` endpoint

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/_msearch -d '
{"type": "type1"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
{"type": "type2"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
'
```

Note: make sure to separate each line by newlines (including the last line)

You'll get two responses in the same order as the requests