# Search should return equal number of record for multiple type

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Search result return equal number of records as per the type.

For Example:

There is a set of records with different type

```
type-1 have 20 records
type-2 have 30 records
type-3 have 5 records
```

User is requesting for all the type with size 10:

Expected Result

```
type-1 should have 4 records
type-2 should have 3 records
type-3 should have 3 records
```

So final result in every type there should at least 2 records.
currently I am using elasticsearch.

My solution: 

For this we have to hit elasticsearch, 3 or more time fetch records for different type. Then we have to divide equally the dataset as per the type. 

This solution have issue

- If I want pagination how can we handle?

If you have any better solution or algorithm for this issue share with me.

Thank you

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your code, along with any associated errors you are receiving: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793682/searching-multiple-types-in-elasticsearch/36793727#36793727