# Dynamically modify the sort criteria based on the previously returned items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents gathered from multiple sources. Some queries return a lot of documents from the same source, which is undesirable. I don't want to filter them out. I want to be able to sort the results so that the first pages contain results from various sources.

Let's say I have crawled a bunch of web sites for tutorials and I store them in documents like this:

```json
{
  "doc": 1,
  "name": "Programming languages. A deep dive.",
  "source": "blog1",
  "url": "https://exmaple.com/"
}
```

```json
{
  "doc": 2,
  "name": "Learn coding in 30 seconds. For real!",
  "source": "blog2",
  "url": "..."
}
```

etc.

I have documents from hundreds or thousands sites, but some sites (blog1) have many tutorials, while other sites have just a few. I search for a popular term (e.g. "chat bots") and I want the first 20 results. I might get 5-10 of them to be from blog1. Then I go to page 2 and I still see many results from blog1. It would look like I'm promoting blog1 and I don't want that. Instead I want to get more diverse results in the first few pages. (I still want to show all the results though if the user loads enough pages. So filtering is not an option.)

One way to achieve this would be to count the number of documents that have been returned per source and to use this count to reduce the importance of this source. Is this possible to be implemented in the elasticsearch query?

Are there alternative solutions?

P.S. I understand that in general this should not be possible, because one can increase the score of a given document above the already returned ones and that would break the sorting contract. But I actually want to decrease them, and that might be possible. Elasticsearch could return an error if the score for some item is greater than the previous one.

*[Edit 1: added an example]*

Comment: Would multi search solve your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793727/4604579 ?

Comment: @Val I don't think so. If I understand your suggestion correctly, I'd have to make the same search for each source. However there are many sources, so this will mean a really big request (and I think a slow response). Also the response can be gigantic.

Comment: What the msearch API offers is to make the same search over different source indexes in one single call and get segregated results for each source index, so that no source index results takes over other from other source indexes. Maybe explain your use in more details with some examples

Comment: I edited the question and added an example.